# RadBeacon Tag distance calculating

Tags: android, ibeacon, rssi

i am using iBeacon from Radius Networks. At the moment I am trying to calculate the distance between android device and RadBeacon Tag by using RSSI. Like David Young mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483254/measure-distance-to-ibeacon-from-android-device) the android devices have got different antenna. My experience with the following forumla  is not very good in combination with my Nexus 7.

```
protected static double calculateAccuracy(int txPower, double rssi) {
  if (rssi == 0) {
    return -1.0; // if we cannot determine accuracy, return -1.
  }

  double ratio = rssi*1.0/txPower;
  if (ratio < 1.0) {
    return Math.pow(ratio,10);
  }
  else {
    double accuracy =  (0.89976)*Math.pow(ratio,7.7095) + 0.111;    
    return accuracy;
  }
}
```

Can anybody provide me a different formula for the distance calculation or some data of a RSSI / distance measurement for different distances?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the best results for a specific device by measuring RSSI at various distances and doing a regression against the above formula to find coefficients for the best fit.  You can read an explanation of the recommended distances here:

http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations.html

You can then import the data into R (the free statistical computing software) and use the nls function (non-linear least squares) to fit the data with a power curve. Here is the power curve equation: function(x, b0, b1, b2) {b0 + b1*(x^b2)}

The nls function solves for the coefficients b0, b1, and b2 which are used in the formula for A, B, and C.

Here's a tutorial on curve fitting in R for more information:

http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5254

Answer (score 0):

This application can help you get coefficients for the distance formula directly or collect all necessary data to calculate by yourself
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.msl.ibeaconchef