# Android how to get Ibeacon X-axis positive and negative value?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

Assume that I have 3 beacons in a horizontal line, I want to check the distance how far away from mid point, so I want to get the positive and negative value of the area. Which mean I want to declare the right or left position of the beacon, so I can estimate the point of current location of the beacon.

This is the something looking like the google map navigation, I want to show the pointer on the circle area with horizontal line, so before that I want to know how to get the positive or negative `X-axis` of the Ibeacon.

[image]

Comment: @davidgyoung can help me have a look? Thank you

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clbeaconregion/1621494-peripheraldata will give you received signal strength indicator which will basically tell you how far you are from the beacon. depending on type of beacon you can then map the signal strength to distance. i recommend overlapping the beacons(ie overlapping circles in your example) if you want "left" and "right" since you can see the subset of beacons returned by the ranging functionality and thereby determine the relative location -some examples of RSSI to distance here https://stackoverflow.com/q/27129740/2435126

Comment: @kkarakk It make sense, can state eg for how to get negative or positive X-axis value of Beacon A if there subset of Beacon A and Beacon B. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are solutions to this problem. but they are complex and we'll beyond what can be answered with a simple code snippet in a StackOverflow answer.

The primary issue is that beacon signals are omnidirectional.  So if you estimate based on the beacon's signal strength that you are 3 meters away, you have no idea which direction.  For the 2D axis in your question, you do not know if you are left or right.

The second problem is that once you get beyond 1-3 m, the noise on the signal measurement gets quite high, making the error on the distance estimate high as well.  *This makes techniques like trilateration work poorly even at such moderate distances.*

For 2D indoor location, the general solution is to use RSSI fingerprinting.  This requires a training data set where a vector of relative signal levels of each beacon is recorded at each point on a 2D grid.  (The same would work for a 1D line.) After training, this data set is used to find the location.   Create a new vector for the relative signal levels of each beacon.  Then search the training set for the closest vector match.  That gives you your position.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I was still fresh on this, this is my first time using iBeacon. Can you provide some source or URL for me for future study it? Appreciate and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can look up a concept known as trilateration or multilateration.  Given that you know the position of at least 3 beacons, positioned in such a way that they're separate but with signal overlaps, you can solve for an arbitrary point between those beacons.

So what your mobile app needs to do is :
1) Have knowledge of the position of each beacon.(e.g x,y) before hand.  These positions can be arbitrary as long as they're consistently applied for all beacons in a coordinate system

2) Scan for each beacon's advertising data which should include that beacon's RSSI.  You can use that to estimate the distance of each detected beacon from your phone.

3) Knowing the position of each beacon and the distance of your phone from each, you can compute the position of the phone relative to the beacons using a multilateration function.  Plenty of libraries out there that can do this, something based on non-linear least squares algorithm can work.

I've done the above on some indoor nav apps, and the quality and accuracy depends highly on your beacon positioning. You need to ensure that in any area you want to cover that there are 3 to 4 beacons positioned nearby to provide decent RSSI readings.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I now trying with it. Thank you :D