# get Distance from Device to iBeacon LE in Android Devices

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

i'm trying to get right distance from my Mobile device(s6-android 5.1) to a hardware IBeacon.

at first start in this form :

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager
            .getBeaconParsers()
            .add(new BeaconParser()
                    .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
  beaconManager.bind(this);
  ...
 }
```

then override this :

```
  @Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

            Log.i(TAG + "region", region.toString());
            Log.i(TAG + " Size ", String.valueOf(beacons.size()));

            for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                Log.i(TAG, " Distance :" + beacon.getId1() + ", " + beacon.getId2() + ", " + beacon.getId3());
            }

            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                logToDisplay("The first beacon " + firstBeacon.toString() + " is about " + firstBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away.");
                Log.i(TAG + " Distance ", beacons.iterator().next().getDistance() + "");
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("RadBeacon",
                Identifier.parse("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"),
                Identifier.parse("1"), Identifier.parse("1")));


    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.i(TAG + "Error", e.toString());
    }
}
```

in top method i can **Log** `region` correctly  that return :

```
  id1: 2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6 id2: 1 id3: 1
```

and other information in Log :

```
   onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=....., mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=null, mManufacturerSpecificData={76=[2, 21, -30, -59, 109, -75, -33, -5, 72, -46, -80, 96, -48, -11, -89, 16, -106, -32, 0, 2, 0, 6, -59]}, mServiceData={00005153-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[67]}, mTxPowerLevel=0, mDeviceName=null], mRssi=-60, mTimestampNanos=431625881888515}
```

but my problem is with `Collection<Beacon> beacons` and this always return **0**

Too i can `Monitor` enter/exit region via :

```
  beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {...}
```

but yet not can get Distance between Mobile and Beacon Hardware;

So after more search find a way and try that :

```
  protected static double calculateAccuracy(int txPower, double rssi) {
    if (rssi == 0) {
        return -1.0; // if we cannot determine accuracy, return -1.
    }

    double ratio = rssi * 1.0 / txPower;
    if (ratio < 1.0) {
        return Math.pow(ratio, 10);
    } else {
        return (0.89976) * Math.pow(ratio, 7.7095) + 0.111;
    }
}
```

for rssi , set mRssi that give in Log and txPower set Static int , but `return value` not was correct.

Now i have tow question :

1. why `Collection<Beacon> beacons` , always return `0` value?
2. how cat achive right and correct `Distance` between Mobile Device and Ibeacon Hardware?

before i try this libraries and resources :

https://forums.estimote.com/t/get-distance-of-beacons/1986

[Measure distance to iBeacon from Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483254/measure-distance-to-ibeacon-from-android-device)

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/43

https://github.com/NickdeDycker/EstimoteIndoorAndroid

http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

http://developer.estimote.com/android/tutorial/part-3-ranging-beacons/

And many other links!

`Thank you for your attention and help`

---

### Edit1

it soo shown in `Logcat` :

```
   W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator﹕ Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
```

@davidgyoung

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

1. Make sure that the beacon is transmitting the identifiers you think it is by using an off-the-shelf scanning app like [Locate.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en)  If the identifiers don't match you can adjust them in the `Region` definition.
2. Add a debug line to the top of `onBeaconServiceConnect` to make sure that is getting called.
3. Verify that you consistently see debug lines in `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` approximately every second.

Comment: i do top tips before(as seen on code) and added Log inside `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` method and this work rightly but my problem is with `Collection<Beacon> beacons`(first argument of  `didRangeBeaconsInRegion `) that always return Zero value.

Comment: Too why shown distance in `Locate` are different with `real` distance between Mobile Device and iBeacin Hardware and not work correctly in calculate Distance? --- it's possible that `ios Mobiles` be more accurate that `android Mobiles` in work with Beacons or not?

Comment: it shown me in `Logcat` too :W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator﹕ Cannot find match for this device.  Using default